# Binding properties in MvxDialogViewController gives me a warning

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am binding a simple view property to a viewmodel in MvxDialogViewController and get the following warning:
        **Warning:  40.44 Failed to create target binding for binding for TestString for TestString**

i have the following code in ViewDidLoad of the view

```
   private string TestString { set; get; }

   public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<FirstView, FirstViewModel>();
            set.Bind(this).For(p => p.TestString).To(vm => vm.TestString);
            set.Apply();
    }
```

and in ViewModel I have:

```
    private string _testString;



    public string TestString
    {
        get { return _testString; }
        set { _testString = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => TestString); }
    }
```

similar works fine with MvxViewController.

I added code above to N_23 sample and still get the same warning. Also my base class for Setup is

```
   public class Setup : MvxTouchDialogSetup
```

Should this binding work for MvxViewController as well?

Thanks you

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding can't access `private` properties.

Try `public` to avoid reflection security issues.

Comment: Thank you once again, how could I not see it ;~(

Comment: FYI - on StackOverflow the best way to "thank you" is to mark the answer as accepted and/or to upvote it :) (It's all about the badges!)